# How to display the binary data of png image in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image-processing, next.js, binary-data

I got binary data of the png image from some third party api.
This is the raw data that I copied after console log the result :
`�PNG

IHDRf�:%PLTE���U��~IDATx�옱�� D[��I�BfBʌP�R_��ݗ~}�,��8���D��3x뭷��"IV��2�����o|`�,��yi.��r�>�%��UN�<#@�o�4$۬�!7 �">PM�d
�6��-ڻ��˫M���4�[�<M�d���_�~w��I�B}Y�!�����&����y`3��.3�˰%�m:.�_'�i�9V�f���)�ի�l   $m���5@nS>y6�)��֝�|;���b*@�yt3�5�y6�4'�$R��S�����|�xR�6OC�$���ԀՐ����a3��ۼ�ҒfL���x�;�^}�S�y�;��ե���0��5���{"=��6��T1���T?_a`lr����`E�<I���Ȫ1B��%����ݒ����Sc��
�ǃ週��E.t%�C�s�YI�2��    �}y�7��}ootM�7H�f�c�w S�rLiI`q��୷޺֟����o���IEND�B`�`

In the browser , when open the network tab the image will be display like this :
[image display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9HOO.png)

How can I display the data above as image like in the picture ? I've try every possible way by convert data to base64 or change accept type from the request header but none of them works.

Any help will be much appreciated.

This is the code to convert data to base64 that I've tried in NextJs, the esimQrCode is the state that contains the binary data of the png image from the apis   :

```
const [esimQrCode, setEsimQrCode] = useState<any>();

 useEffect(() => {
    loadQrCode();
}, []);


const loadQrCode = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(API_GET_QRCODE() 
    });

    const qrCodeData = res?.data;
    
    console.log(qrCodeData) // => the result will look like the 
    binary data above 
    
    setEsimQrCode(qrCodeData);
    if (!process.browser) {
        return;
    }
}

if(!esimQrCode){
   return <div/>
}

const blob = new Blob([esimQrCode], { type: "image/png" });
const base64Data = Buffer.from(esimQrCode).toString("base64");

return <img src={`data:image/png;base64,${base64Data}`} />
```

The result of the above code is the empty image icon.

Thank you for reading !

Comment: `I've tried` ... and what is the result

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for new users, and read the help center article about [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I know at  least one issue you might be facing, but "it doesn't work" is not enough information to know if it's the right one.

Comment: @traktor : the esimQrCode is the binary data of the png image that I post in the beginning

Comment: `Buffer` is not a global variable in browsers. Please update the question with details of the environment, and provide the type of  `esimQrCode` - "binary data" is often used to refer to both strings and array buffers.

Comment: @traktor : thank you for your comment , I've updated the question and code , hope it will make the questions more clear

Comment: Great. I'm not familiar with the work stack and suggest dropping  question tags 'base64` and ``png` in favor of 'react' and 'nextjs`  to reach readers using those products. Good luck.

Comment: @traktor already updated the tag as your advice . Thank you so much for your help !